# Error test exception in Junit eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I kept getting error (not fail) when I tried to test the exception. Also tried @rule. Same thing happens.

```
public Money addSameCurrency(Money other) {
    if (!currency.equals(other.currency)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    Money m = new Money(amount + other.amount, currency);
    return m;
}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testExceptionIsThrown() {
    Money m1 = new Money(10, "USD");
    Money m2 = new Money(15, "EUR");
    Money sum = m1.addSameCurrency(m2);
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Post the full stack trace or error (do you mean a compilation error?) message you get.

Comment: Does your test extend `junit.frameworkTestCase` directly or indirectly? If so, that would likely make the test run as a JUnit3-style test (so the `@Test` annotation would be ignored)

Comment: Thanks NamshubWriter. I did extends TestCase. It works if not extend that class.

Comment: I am curious why there were down votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that your test extends `junit.frameworkTestCase` directly or indirectly. If so, that would likely make the test run as a JUnit3-style test (so the @Test annotation would be ignored)